# Why can't I propose an edit on this question?

Tags: support, editing

I wanted to edit the tags on [this question](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/30/83), which is open, not locked, and not community wiki.  I have under 1k rep so (now that we're in public beta) I know my edit would have to be reviewed.  That's fine.

But the "edit" link isn't there -- it's grayed out and not clickable.  Why is that?

[image: screen shot]

The edit link is available for answers on that question and on other questions; it's not a general problem.  It's just that one post, near as I can tell.

(The change I was going to propose is to remove [bad-moderation](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bad-moderation), which I think is a suboptimal tag anyway, and replace it with the pre-existing [conflicts](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conflicts).)

Comment: What does the mouseover title say? ;)

Comment: @FEichinger - oh!  It was slow enough in coming that I never saw it until you pointed it out.  (I had to park my mouse there for a couple seconds -- don't know if that's Chrome, the site, or something else.)

Comment: +1 for the question, but -1 for not enough jQuery. -1 for oddly-sized freehand circle and +1 for asking on meta. Oh yeah, another +1 for the question. Net: +1 Anyway, I never knew about this feature. I knew that if you had 2K it would say `edit (1)`...

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin 1k, since we're in public beta.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin if I'd made the circle perfectly-shaped (probably an ellipsis, actually...), somebody would complain that it wasn't "freehand enough".  Some days you can't win. :-)  (And, up, what am I supposed to do about jQuery?  Even if I knew how to read it, surely you don't think it's reasonable for people to have to crawl through the page source and its attendant JavaScript to understand site behavior.  Right?  And yes, I recognize the light tone of your comment and am attempting to follow suit.)

Comment: I can confirm that I would have complained about the lack of freehanded-ness in the freehand circle had it been a perfect ellipsis.

Comment: @MonicaCellio *Pssst!* That was a small experiment to see how SE infested our meta was yet. :D (Just kidding) Anyway, this is an odd thing to do, especially for mobile. Most users don't even know about tooltips, so it is kinda pointless. It might be better to let someone click on it still and then show a message...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Here's why!

Stack Exchange has the beautiful habit of telling you (sometimes by hidden means) why you can't do something. In this case, the mouseover title of the edit link reveals the answer:

[image: Edit is pending review]

Someone has already submitted an edit suggestion, which (due to our lack of eligible reviewers) has not been reviewed yet. As long as this edit is pending review, no other edit suggestions may be submitted to this post. Only users with the edit privilege can edit (and thereby review and/or override) the suggested edit.

Comment: a more practical solution: upvote all FEichinger's posts so he can deal with the pending edit :S

Comment: @Braiam It would be easier to just upvote Monica the missing 180 rep, than me the missing 340. I mean, I appreciate the notion, but still. :P

Comment: Umm... if I upvote all your post you get 130 reps, and Monica only 90... so anyways we are sort... :(